# Xammp/php: cant find file path

Tags: php, html, xampp, adobe-brackets

I use brackets for editing and live previewing my code, but when I change the names of my folders live preview doesn't work. Here is the error message:

> Warning: require(header.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\Programmering\Xammp\Files\htdocs\webside1\pages\index.php on line 13
>   Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'header.php'
>
> (include_path='D:\Programmering\Xammp\Files\htdocs\webside1\pages/../') in D:\Programmering\Xammp\Files\htdocs\webside1\pages\index.php on line 13

Here is my index.php code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <title>Home - Awt-technologies</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

    <body id="indexbody">
        <?php //include_once('D:\Programmering\Xammp\Files\htdocs\webside1\pages\header.php');
        set_include_path(dirname(__FILE__)."/../");
        require 'header.php';
        //Checks if user is logged in
        if(isset($_SESSION['name'])) {
            include_once "templates\loggedin.php";
        }
        ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

I checked the path and it should work but doesn't. Here is a picture of my files in brackets:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: The error is because header.php is not in the same relative directory as index.php (according to your screenshot).

Comment: Off-topic here but... Wow this editor looks really nice. Is it better than sublime?

Comment: @PhiterFernandes I have not tried sublime yet, but brackets have always work very good for me.

Comment: @Andy I'm not sure what you mean. What can i do to fix it?

Comment: @AndreasWT PHP uses forward slashes, "/", you're using backslashes, "\" which is common in Windows.

Comment: @Tiffany I changed all my backslashes to fowardslashes in all files, but it still doesn't work

Comment: You'll need to direct to the correct path of the header.php file using "../" which goes down one directory level, until you reach the directory level that the header.php file is in.  You many need to direct to a specific directory path, like ```../../includes/header.php```.

Comment: Error reporting would have been your friend today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your index.php is in a different folder than your header.php file.

You'll need to change the require path to `../templates/header.php`.